# How to protect mysql-server when upgrading ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, server, upgrade, mysql, 15.10

Straight-forward. How do I block upgrading MySQL Server when upgrading Ubuntu from 15.10 to 16.04.3.

Before starting, I held onto various MySQL-5.6 packages with `apt-mark hold <pack>`. Then, I followed the upgrade instructions from [the official notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_or_15.10) on a clone of the target server. I can recreate the initial conditions.

However, the upgrade procedure attempted to install mysql-5.7. Looking with `dpkg -l | grep mysql` I now have

- `rc mysql-server-5.6 -> Desired:Remove,  Status:Conf-files`
- `iU mysql-server     -> Desired:Install, Status:Unpacked`
- `iF mysql-server-5.7 -> Desired:Install, Status:halF-conf`

and other `mysql-*-core-5.7` packages installed (`ii`).

#### Instructions I followed

> To upgrade on a server system:
>
> - Install the update-manager-core package if it is not already installed.
> - Make sure the /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades is set to normal if you are using 15.10, lts if you are using 14.04 LTS.
> - Launch the upgrade tool with the command sudo do-release-upgrade.
> - Follow the on-screen instructions.

Comment: Why do you not want to update MySQL? There's a [number of vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list.php?vendor_id=93&product_id=21801&version_id=153836&page=1&hasexp=0&opdos=0&opec=0&opov=0&opcsrf=0&opgpriv=0&opsqli=0&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opfileinc=0&opginf=0&cvssscoremin=0&cvssscoremax=0&year=0&month=0&cweid=0&order=3&trc=1&sha=f1bda2f3c1623aecec293e406e42fa311168e297) that you probably want to get rid of. You can update and keep all your data.

Comment: There are certain features regarding select queries that exist on 5.6 that did not make it to 5.7 even through compatibility options. Until I can find workarounds, I have to keep 5.6. However, I still have to upgrade the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems something went wrong on the first couple of simulations. I changed something in my script and it is now holding perfectly.

So for anyone who were to cross this question, `apt-mark hold <package>` does work as expected

Comment: Hey, i m having issue with update. .. It seems when update comes mysql turns off and never turns back on (unless i do it) :( i tried `apt-mark hold mysql-server` but it still turns off. .. Did you put on hold any other mysql packages?

Comment: It is probable that there is an update routine being executed that causes a service shutdown. I can't help you except by reminding you to check your `syslog` when it happens (check your `mysql/error.log` to confirm that it is a normal shutdown and not a crash). Logs in my system are located in the standard directory `/var/log`

Comment: Thanks for reply! I already checked my logs it seems like it just shutdown without crash. .. Today i added `apt-mark hold mysql-server-5.7` so maybe that one will do the trick

Comment: But was the shutdown registered in your `syslog`? If so, you may have an automated system routine that does not care wether your packages were hold or not. Be careful out there

Comment: Yep `syslog` told `Feb  7 06:35:45 portalz systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
Feb  7 06:35:57 portalz systemd[1]: Reloading.
Feb  7 06:35:57 portalz systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Community Server...
Feb  7 06:35:59 portalz systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.`

Comment: `apt-mark hold mysql-server-5.7` did the trick :) Thanks!